# DouglasPeuckerSimplifier usage

Tags: java, geo

I am attempting to reduce shape files generated from OSM path data. I am using the DouglasPeuckerSimplifier implementation from VTS.
I want to build up a geojson of the routemap for a specific GTFS (general transit feed spec). I cant just use the set straight from the map as it's too heavy, I end up with multi-megabyte size json files.

My code looks like this, I have incuded the loop to populate the input just to give you some confidence that I have a valid input array. What I am querying is really just the last 3 lines, and the general concept of taking a path from OSM and reducing the number of points in it, which I thought was exactly what Douglas-Peucker was all about.

```
                ArrayList<Geometry> points = new ArrayList <Geometry>();
                GeometryFactory gf= new GeometryFactory();
                for (Object sh : shape_points){
                    double thisShapeLat=((Shapes)sh).getshapePtLat();
                    double thisShapeLon=((Shapes)sh).getshapePtLon();
                    // void identical consecutive points
                    if (lastShapeLat == thisShapeLat && lastShapeLon == thisShapeLon) continue;
                    lastShapeLat = thisShapeLat;
                    lastShapeLon = thisShapeLon;
                    Coordinate coord= new Coordinate(thisShapeLon,thisShapeLat);
                    // System.err.println("added coord="+coord);
                    points.add(gf.createPoint(coord));
                }

                Geometry[] points_ar = (Geometry [])points.toArray(new Geometry[points.size()]);
                GeometryCollection geometries = new GeometryCollection(points_ar, gf);
                DouglasPeuckerSimplifier simplifier = new DouglasPeuckerSimplifier(geometries);
                simplifier.setDistanceTolerance(0.00001);
                Geometry result=simplifier.getResultGeometry();
```

No matter what value I set for the tolerance, I get the same points in (points) as out (result). It's not doing anything at all.
I have also called simplify() as a static, with the same result, i.e nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a LineString not GeometryCollection for tyhe parameters to simplify.

```
                Coordinate list2[] = new Coordinate[coords.size()];
                list2 = coords.toArray(list2);
                CoordinateArraySequence cas=new CoordinateArraySequence(list2);

                LineString ls = new LineString(cas,gf);
                Geometry result=DouglasPeuckerSimplifier.simplify(ls,0.001);
```